# ConvertFrom-JSON | Where-Object, does not work

Tags: powershell

I did the following script, initially I used Where-Object but it didn't work, then I used foreach, the question is: **why doesn't it work with Where-Object?**

The code with Where-Object returns the whole array, then I used foreach and it works great.

```
$conexionesBD = @"
[{
        "name": "General",
        "data": {
            "instance": "INSTANCE01",
            "userName": "user_gen",
            "database": "general_data"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Config",
        "data": {
            "instance": "INSTANCE02",
            "userName": "user_congig",
            "database": "config_data"
        }
    }
]
"@

# With Where-Object doesn't work
$conexionesBD | ConvertFrom-JSON | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'General'}

<# Result:
General @{instance=INSTANCE01; userName=user_gen; database=general_data}  
Config  @{instance=INSTANCE02; userName=user_congig; database=config_data}
#>


# Works fine with foreach
foreach ($conexion in ($conexionesBD | ConvertFrom-JSON)){
    if($conexion.name -eq 'Conexiones'){
        break
    }
}

$conexion

<# Result:
Config  @{instance=INSTANCE02; userName=user_congig; database=config_data}
#>
```

My PowerShell Version is:

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                   
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.610                                                                                                           
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                 
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                 
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.610                                                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                         
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                     
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: From memory, ```ConvertFrom-Json``` in powershell 5.1 returns a single array object in the pipeline, rather than “streaming” the individual items. As a result your ```where-object``` is inspecting the array, not the items. However, the ```foreach``` *does* enumerate over the items.

Comment: Also from memory, the behaviour is different in powershell core / 6.0+, where it “unwraps” the array and streams the items out to the next command in the pipeline. There’s a bunch of issues in the GitHub repo about this - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424 for example

Answer (score 1):

its a bug i think, solution? try this :

```
$array=$conexionesBD | ConvertFrom-JSON
$array | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'General'}
```

Or this :

```
($conexionesBD | ConvertFrom-JSON) | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'General'}
```

Comment: They work great, thanks. Can you tell me why they work and the direct way doesn't?

Comment: hum i'm not sure, i think it's a bug